# Why do we use Bequerel to measure Radioactivity in food?

Tags: nuclear-physics, radioactivity

Wouldn't it be better to use the equivalent dose?

Comment: It's difficult, I guess. The amount of radioactivity does not just cummulate linearly in your body when you eat it and it's quite difficult to say how long it stays in the metabolism...

Comment: In addition to Martin's correct answer (it's hard enough to measure, at all, let alone to establish the isotope dependent dose), food can not contain more than trace amounts of radioactivity, or all hell has broken out, already. There is no safe established equivalent dose for ingested radioactivity.

Comment: I used to approximate the activity of a banana as part of party trick we did for people visiting a place I worked at that had a low background Ge-detector system. But "decays" isn't a good measure of health effects.

Answer (score 1):

Standard way to evaluate the risk associated with eating the contaminated food is to start with the ingested activity (Bq) and then estimate the effective dose using the [conversion coefficients](http://www.icrp.org/docs/P%20119%20JAICRP%2041(s)%20Compendium%20of%20Dose%20Coefficients%20based%20on%20ICRP%20Publication%2060.pdf).

Many parameters must be considered in this calculation- for instance the age of the guy who eat such food, chemical form of the radionuclide...

Talking about the equivalent dose of an apple for instance is nonsense (from the radiation protection point of view). The dose (equivalent or effective) is always related to the consumer, not food.